# Drush can't bootstrap sites

Tags: 7, drush, bootstrapping

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server where I have one Drupal 8 and two Drupal 7 sites. I have installed drush 8.4.5 which works great for the Drupal 8 site but on the 7 ones it can't bootstrap.

After some googling I found that a very common reason for this is when the `mysql` command is not in the PATH, but this is not the case here, in fact all db commands like `drush sqlc` work fine.

Here is the output when I run `drush status -d`

```
Cache HIT cid: 8.4.5-commandfiles-0-a3cd8cb920bcde827cc232180c6d7f26 [0.01 sec, 3.07 MB]                                                                                                             [debug]
Loaded alias @widgets from file /home/user/.drush/lsv.aliases.drushrc.php [0.07 sec, 8.05 MB]                                                                                                    [notice]
Cache SET cid: 8.4.5-alias-path--043cb3d69eb478aa2b3e38377546b6de [0.07 sec, 8.05 MB]                                                                                                                [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.07 sec, 8.06 MB]                                                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Trying to bootstrap as far as we can. [0.07 sec, 8.07 MB]                                                                                                                                            [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.08 sec, 8.42 MB]                                                                                                                              [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.59 root directory at /var/www/html/widgets [0.08 sec, 8.42 MB]                                                                                                              [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=7) [0.08 sec, 6.93 MB]                                                                                                                                           [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.4.5-commandfiles-1-5c1ee58258b6846d7827dff1da4d928c [0.08 sec, 6.93 MB]                                                                                                             [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.4.5-annotationfiles-1-47d8cbe4e8ce28c2c1c5b0f779e97f8a [0.08 sec, 6.93 MB]                                                                                                          [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.08 sec, 6.94 MB]                                                                                                                              [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site widgets.bb at sites/default [0.08 sec, 6.94 MB]                                                                                                                          [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 2 (max=7) [0.09 sec, 6.94 MB]                                                                                                                                           [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.09 sec, 6.94 MB]                                                                                                                     [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 3 (max=7) [0.09 sec, 6.96 MB]                                                                                                                                           [debug]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.09 sec, 7.02 MB]                                                                                                                                                            [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_teStTK --database=widgets --host=127.0.0.1 --silent  < /tmp/drush_79ibgU
  1
sql-query: SHOW TABLES; [0.1 sec, 7.02 MB]                                                                                                                                                          [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_Rwkses --database=widgets --host=127.0.0.1 --silent  < /tmp/drush_VA3WyB
  actions
  authmap
  [...remaining site db tables]
Bootstrap phase bootstrap_drupal_database() failed to validate; continuing at bootstrap_drupal_configuration(). [0.12 sec, 7.05 MB]                                                                  [debug]
Found command: core-status (commandfile=core) [0.12 sec, 7.05 MB]                                                                                                                                [bootstrap]
Loading outputformat engine. [0.14 sec, 8.55 MB]                                                                                                                                                    [notice]
Calling hook drush_core_status [0.15 sec, 8.81 MB]                                                                                                                                                   [debug]
Returned from hook drush_core_status [0.15 sec, 8.82 MB]                                                                                                                                             [debug]
 Drupal version         :  7.59
 Site URI               :  mysite.com
 Database driver        :  mysql                                                       
 Database hostname      :  127.0.0.1                                                   
 Database port          :                                                              
 Database username      :  dbuser
 Database name          :  dbname
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                                                
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini                                    
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                                                       
 Drush script           :  /home/user/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php 
 Drush version          :  8.4.5                                                       
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                                        
 Drush configuration    :                                                              
 Drush alias files      :  /home/user/.drush/mysite.aliases.drushrc.php                
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/html/mysite                                       
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php                                  
 Site path              :  sites/default                                               

Command dispatch complete [0.15 sec, 8.86 MB]                                                                                                                                                       [notice]
 Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page   0.067      1      66.81
```

As you can see I've already tried using a drush alias (no special configuration there) but without changing anything.

Comment: Did you do the [One Drush for all projects](https://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/install/#composer-one-drush-for-all-projects) installation?

Comment: Is the site is hosted on Acquia ? If yes try to run drush from docroot older not from the folder above it.

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, I installed drush 8.4.5 globally using composer (also tried with 7). It works great for Drupal 8 projects just not for the 7 ones.

Comment: @miststudent2011 no it's not on Acquia, it's on an Ubuntu 18.04 server, in general I've tried running it from the project root, the "sites/default" folder, as well as using an alias, all still having the same behavior

Comment: I'd check if there's any logic on settings.php that could be interfering or any files included/required from there